# Get X Y coordinates of image

Tags: matlab, matrix, coordinates

I need to find out how can i put obtained coordinates form image into a matrix and saving it.

```
clc
clear all
k=imread('l.jpg');
for i=1:4
figure(1),imshow(k)
axis on
hold on
title(i)
[x,y]=ginput(1)
pause
end
```

Comment: When you read an image you already get a matrix, and the (row, column) position of a pixel is exactly what you call (x, y) coordinate.

Comment: you are already doing it, with `x` and `y`. If you want to store them after the loop, you need to learn basic matlab, read about indexing and arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments have suggested, here is a method thats stores the values into arrays by indexing the arrays `x` and `y` using and indexing variable `i` that is incremented on each loop iteration. As you probably know any <kbd>Key</kbd> must be pressed to continue the loop. The built-in MATLAB image `'tire.tif'` is used in this example.

```
clc;
clear;

Image = imread('tire.tif');
imshow(Image);
axis on
Number_Of_Coordinates = 4;

x = zeros(1,Number_Of_Coordinates);
y = zeros(1,Number_Of_Coordinates);

for i = 1: Number_Of_Coordinates
    title( i)
    [x(i),y(i)] = ginput(1);
    fprintf("Coordinates Stored: (%f,%f) -> Press and key to continue\n",x(i),y(i));
    pause
end
```